# Ajax calls distorts layout in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, layout

I am working on a website that includes several simple ajax calls via jQuery to load contents from another page into a modal window.  Everything works great in 'modern browsers,' but in all versions of Internet Explorer (IE 9 included), when the link is clicked to open the modal window, it changes the layout of the page.

What I think is happening is that IE thinks the popup is the actual screen size and then is pulling in my media queries and applying them to the page.  I have used  classes on the HTML element in the page to differentiate between IE and other browsers and have tried excluding IE from all of the media queries, but this has not completely worked.

Below is a link to the page. If you use IE 9 and scroll down to the 'About Us' section and click on the link, you will see the layout change in the header.  However, if you scroll to 'Where We Are' and click the link, it is the layout inside the modal window that becomes distorted.

Web link: http://accesstca.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just a side note, I love your site! Awesome, creative design.

Comment: Couldn't recreate the issue in IE8, but oddly the main background images were all stretched vertically by about 50% even before clicking link, but again unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding classes to the html element to target IE using conditional comments (http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/). Then I used these classes to exclude IE certain styles in my media queries.